# Is it possible to run ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: mono, c#, monodevelop

I've seen somewhere that MonoDev is allowing that, but when I installed Ubuntu and MonoDev I did find only MVC1 as an option for project to create. So maybe someone does know if it really is supporting ASP.NET MVC3 (C#) and if it is then how to set it up. Also, what about DB? Will I be able to run apps that require Linq2SQL model data-binder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### yes it is possible to run asp.net mvc3 apps on linux box.

See http://twistedcode.net/blog/post/2011/01/17/Mono-and-ASPNET-MVC-v3.aspx for details

It's not very easy or pleasant process since you will need to install mono 2.10.4 or above.
(install guide http://coderinserepeat.com/blog/archive/2011/Aug-14.html)

AFAIK LinqToSQL will not work, however you can use some alternatives like Nhibernate or something simplier like Massive https://github.com/robconery/massive or ServiceStack.OrmLite https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite - not to mention all of which will let you use some linux DB engine like PostgreSQL or MySql.

Comment: I strongly recommend ServiceStack.OrmLite as an data access alternative: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

Answer (score 1):

I use a mono-dll I am making, it seems to work fine with [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

---

```
Ubuntu 12.04 Precise/Server (Server)
MacOSX 10.6 Snow Leopard (Workstation)
MonoDevelop 3.0.4.6
Mono Runtime:
    Mono 2.11.4 (master/417ec78)
    GTK 2.24.11
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 211040000
```

---